# D3 v4 - make a horizontal bar chart with fixed width

Tags: d3.js, height, bar-chart, fixed

I have made a horizontal bar chart using d3 v4, which works fine except for one thing. I am not able to make the bar height fixed. I am using bandwidth() currently and if i replace it with a fixed value say (15) the problem is that it does not align with the y axis label/tick http://jsbin.com/gigesi/3/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var w = 200;
var h = 400;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .attr("transform", "translate(80,30)");

var data = [
            {Item: "Item 1", count: "11"},
            {Item: "Item 2", count: "14"},
            {Item: "Item 3", count: "10"},
            {Item: "Item 4", count: "14"}
           ];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .rangeRound([0,w])
               .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                   return d.count;
               })]);

var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
               .rangeRound([h,0]).padding(0.2)
               .domain(data.map(function(d) {
                   return d.Item;
             }));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
svg.append('g')
   .attr('class','axis')
   .call(yAxis);
svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
       .attr('width', function(d,i) {
           return xScale(d.count);
        })
       .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
       .attr('y', function(d, i) {
           return yScale(d.Item);
       }).attr("fill","#000");
```

Comment: I tried making this change .attr('height', 15 + this.data.length /  this.yScale.bandwidth()) but that does not help in alignment with the ticks when the data length has 1 or 2 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **y axis** seemed to be off **SVG** in the link you provided. (Maybe you have `overflow: visible;` for the SVG.

Anyway, I've added a few margins to the chart so that the whole chart is visible. Here it is (ignore the link description):

[DEMO: H BAR CHART WITH HEIGHT POSITIONING TO THE TICKS](http://jsbin.com/xivarejeya/edit?html,css,js,output)

Relevant code changes:

1. As you are using a scale band, the height is computed within. You just need to use `.bandWidth()`.

   ```
   .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
   ```
2. Added a margin and transformed the axis and the bars to make the whole chart visible : 
   : I'm assigning margins so that the `y-axis` is within the viewport of the SVG which makes it easier to adjust the left margin based on the tick value as well. And I think this should be a standard practice.
   Also, if you notice, the `rects` i.e. **bars** are now a part of `<g class="bars"></g>`. Inspect the DOM if you'd like. This would be useful for complex charts with a LOT of elements but it's always a good practice.

   ```
   var margin = {top: 10, left: 40, right: 30, bottom: 10};

   var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
         .rangeRound([0,w-margin.left-margin.right])

   var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([h-margin.top-margin.bottom,0]).padding(0.2)

   svg.append('g')
      .attr('class','axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left+', '+margin.top+')')
   ```

Try changing the data and the **bar height** will adjust and align according to the ticks. Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**
Initially, I thought you were facing a problem placing the bars at the center of the y tick but as you said you needed fixed height bars, here's a quick addition to the above code that lets you do that. I'll add another approach using the padding (inner and outer) sometime soon.

[Updated JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/jacumagoje/edit?html,css,js,output)

To position the bar exactly at the position of the axis tick, I'm moving the bar from top to the *scale's bandwidth* that is calculated by `.bandWidth()` which will the position it starting right from the tick and now subtracting half of the **desired height half** from it so that the center of the bar matches the tick `y`. Hope this explains.

```
.attr('height', 15)
.attr('transform', 'translate(0, '+(yScale.bandwidth()/2-7.5)+')')
```

Comment: Hi Shashank,Thanks for your reply. If you notice i am using the bandwidth() already. What i want is the band height be fixed irrespective of the data set. So say it should always be 15. The problem setting the height manually is that the bar then does not align with the ticks and y axis. I think the clue is in paddingInner / outer but that is where i am getting confused.

Comment: And sorry a typo in the question it should be fixed height instead of fixed width.

Comment: Updated the answer with a new link. Check that out.

Comment: Thanks very much!! It works like a charm.. So 7.5 i get it that you are using half of the required bandwidth.. But why the initial half of yScale.bandwidth()? Can you please also explain the reasoning behind the formula? Just because i think this will help when doing a double bar chart too?

Comment: Oh no worries. I looked at your solution more carefully.. You are transforming the bar to the right position.. That was even more simpler!! Thanks again

Comment: My bad. I wrote that in a hurry as I had to get back to work. I see that you figured that out but I've added explanation anyway (for the record). :)